# Is it possible to create asp.NET site with xaml with code behind?

Tags: asp.net

AS wpf/silverlight is pretty good with xaml and code behind. Is it possible use it for ASP.NET web site?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. But you can use ASP.NET Web Forms. Instead of XAML you use HTML with custom controls. Each page can have a code behind written in C# or VB.

Comment: thanks. The way for data binding for asp.net only available for MVC? I don't like UI parts for MVC although its architecture pretty good. Many new thing only for MVC UI, not generic. That why I want to know if there is any certain way to reuse xaml for Asp.NET(for html).

Comment: @KentZhou I don't understand your question. ASP.NET Web Forms does have data binding to controls in a manner somewhat similar to data binding in WPF applications.